# Count pairs of distinct elements using Xquery

Tags: xquery, basex

I would count all distinct items considering parent and child tag.

For example, if the document contains:

```
    <root>
      <A value="5.1">
        <B value="3.5">
          <C value="1.4">
            <D value="0.2">
              <E value="X"/>
            </D>
          </C>
        </B>
      </A>
      <A value="5.1">
        <B value="3.5">
          <C value="1.4">
            <D value="0.4">
              <E value="Y"/>
            </D>
          </C>
        </B>
      </A>
      <A value="4.6">
        <B value="3.1">
          <C value="1.5">
            <D value="0.2">
              <E value="X"/>
            </D>
          </C>
        </B>
      </A>
      <A value="5.0">
        <B value="3.6">
          <C value="1.4">
            <D value="0.2">
              <E value="X"/>
            </D>
          </C>
        </B>
      </A>
    </root>
```

I would count all distinct items for AB, ABC, ABCD, BCD etc.

I tried this xquery command, but got only the distinct values ​​for individual items:

```
count(distinct-values(doc('partitioncollection')/root/A/@value)) -> 3
count(distinct-values(doc('partitioncollection')/root/B/@value)) -> 3
count(distinct-values(doc('partitioncollection')/root/C/@value)) -> 2
```

More specifically, if I want calculate the counts of all possibile pairs of value, the results should show:

```
A/B : 3
A/B/C : 3
A/B/C/D : 4
A/B/C/D/E : 4
B/C : 3
B/C/D : 4
B/C/D/E : 4
C/D : 3
C/D/E : 3
D/E : 2

C/E : should be 3 because there are 3 distinct pairs of values: 

<C value="1.4"><E value="X"/>
<C value="1.4"><E value="Y"/>
<C value="1.5"><E value="X"/>

A/D : should be 4 because there are 4 distinct pairs of values: 

<A value="5.1"><D value="0.2">
<A value="5.1"><D value="0.4">
<A value="4.6"><D value="0.2">
<A value="5.0"><D value="0.2">
etc.
```

Being computationally complex, I believe it is easier to create a function that takes as a single set of tags (i.e. A-D or C-E etc.) and returns the value of the counter

Comment: I could understand that `A` and `B` elements form a "pair" of parent/child elements, but why is "ABC" a pair, why "BC" not? And is that document structure known to contain only the same kind of elements in the same nesting structure so it suffices to look downwards and compare `@value` attributes or is the an arbitrary number and name and nesting of elements?

Comment: The number of items has been set from the beginning. But if you consider the example just added, maybe my problem is clearer to you.

Answer (score 2):

I am still not sure the problem is precisely described (it is not clear whether the structure is always `A/B/C/D/E`, it is not clear whether for deeper levels you only want to compare e.g. `B/C` if they are children of an `A` with the same value) but in general I think this can be solve using grouping and recursion; I came up with

```
declare function local:distinct-descendants($elements as element()*) as xs:string*
{
    for $element-group in $elements[*]
    group by $element-name := node-name($element-group)
    let $max-depth := max($element-group/count(.//*)) + 1
    for $level in 2 to $max-depth
      let $groups := 
        for $path-group in $element-group
        group by $group-path := string-join(subsequence($path-group/descendant-or-self::*/node-name(), 1, $level), '/')
        for $value-group in $path-group
        group by $value-seq := string-join(subsequence($value-group/descendant-or-self::*/@value, 1, $level), '|')
        return head($group-path)
      for $level-group in $groups
      group by $level-path := $level-group
      order by head($level)
      return $level-path || ' : ' || count($level-group)
    ,
    if ($elements/*) then local:distinct-descendants($elements/*) else ()
};

local:distinct-descendants(root/*)
```

At https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kz/4 this outputs

```
A/B : 3
A/B/C : 3
A/B/C/D : 4
A/B/C/D/E : 4
B/C : 3
B/C/D : 4
B/C/D/E : 4
C/D : 3
C/D/E : 3
D/E : 2
```

I get the same result with BaseX.

The code might be a bit too complicated if the structure is always `A/B/C/D/E`, in that case the first grouping on the `node-name()` is not needed.

I also had to group twice inside, on the "path" sequence (e.g. `A/B/C`) and on the `@value` sequence, there might be easier ways but I wasn't able to relate unique `@value` sequences with the the nesting structure without doing the duplicate grouping.

Perhaps

```
declare function local:distinct-descendants($elements as element()*) as xs:string*
{
    let $max-depth := max($elements/count(descendant-or-self::*))
    for $level in 2 to $max-depth
      let $groups := 
        for $path-group in $elements
        group by 
          $group-path := string-join(subsequence($path-group/descendant-or-self::*/node-name(), 1, $level), '/'),
          $value-seq := string-join(subsequence($path-group/descendant-or-self::*/@value, 1, $level), '|')
        return head($group-path)
      for $level-group in $groups
      group by $level-path := $level-group
      order by head($level)
      return $level-path || ' : ' || count($level-group)
    ,
    if ($elements/*) then local:distinct-descendants($elements/*) else ()
};

local:distinct-descendants(root/*)
```

at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kz/6 is a bit simpler and still does the job.

I think the previous two attempts work fine as long as the subtrees all have one child but break if not; thus in the general case of an arbitrary number of child elements it seems necessary to compute paths and values from descendants and group them:

```
declare variable $value-separator as xs:string external := '|';

declare function local:distinct-descendants($elements as element()*) as xs:string*
{
    for $element-group in $elements[*]
    group by $element-name := node-name($element-group)
    return
        (
            let $groups :=
                for $descendant-group in $element-group//*
                group by
                    $path-key := string-join(($descendant-group/ancestor-or-self::* except $element-group/ancestor::*)/node-name(), '/'),
                    $value-key := string-join(($descendant-group/ancestor-or-self::* except $element-group/ancestor::*)/@value, $value-separator)
                return $path-key
            for $path-group in $groups
            group by $path-key := $path-group
            return $path-key || ' : ' || count($path-group)
            ,
            if ($element-group/*) then local:distinct-descendants($element-group/*) else ()
        )
};

local:distinct-descendants(root/*)
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kz/14

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried your solutions and they work properly. But you didn't consider that I would also have the unordered combination, such as CE, AC, AD, ABE, ACE and so on. How can I correct your code?

Morover, I prefer last solution because it is the least complex computationally.

Comment: Isn't it easier to think of a function that takes a path as input and returns the requested count?

Comment: I commented both in a comment to your question as well as in the answer that that single example input without even given the exact result does not precisely describe the problem, so I am afraid it is you who didn't consider to describe the problem precisely. Throwing in now `CE, AC, AD, ABE, ACE` as a second example, again without showing the exact structure nor the result you want doesn't look like a serious attempt to exactly describe the possible inputs and outputs.

Comment: As for your comment to write a function that takes a path and returns the count, do you have any known paths you can feed to that function because you know the document structure or at least know the elements that are relevant for the comparison?

Comment: I'm sorry. I know the structure of the document and all the items have a single child. I've two possibilities for my problem: 1) As in your proposed solutions, I can calculate all possible counts of all paths;

Comment: 2) Considering that the number of descendants can be large, I would like calculate the count of a single path to improve the performance. I think that the second solution is more simple. Now I hope that the problem is clear. Thank you!

Comment: I hope I have explained the problem clearly. @Martin Honnen

Comment: @StefanoCirillo, well, I have spent some time to write some code as suggestions on how to approach it and shown it in the answer, now try to work with it and adapt it to your needs (which are still not precisely defined for me, for instance your "the unordered combination, such as CE, AC, AD, ABE, ACE" at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kz/15 gives some result but you have nowhere explained which you want or in what way the suggested code doesn't work).

Comment: Your proposed solutions are very good for me, but they are not complete. I try to describe my problem again: I would count all distinct elements with different value considering single tag or multiple tag (like your proposed solutions). All items in the tree are structured in the same way (as here https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kz/17). I want consider also the combinations of tag that not are direct descendents. (Now I update the example in the question)

Comment: Suggestion: I wrote the query in SQL: **select count (*) from (select count (*) from the calc group from B, C, E);** Where the attribute _B, C, E_ can be replaced with all other attributes and get the required value.

Comment: Sorry, my ability to come up with XQuery based on SQL fragments is rather limited, perhaps add a tag for SQL to your question and edit it to show the relevant details and results you get for your SQL and ask for help doing the same in XQuery. It might be better to start a new question if you shift the focus on inferring an XQuery approach from an SQL query.

Comment: I suggest an SQL solution to simplify understanding, but I would like to update one of your proposed solutions. Can you help me?

Comment: Isn't the desired result you have shown in the edit of the question exactly the one that BaseX gives you for the code from, for instance https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kz/17? It is hard for me to tell whether you yourself have a clear understanding of all kind of input and desired outputs you might have or want to have, but you haven't managed to communicate them clearly. I have not understood so far how you want to treat the same pair `b/c` in `<a value="a1"><b value="b"><c value="c"/></b></a><a value="a2"><b value="b"><c value="c"/></b></a>` with different parents.

Comment: If the only aim left is to reduce code complexity, perhaps also ask that as a new question with a clear focus on that.

Comment: No. I don't want to reduce the complexity of the code, I suggest the solution that reads a set of tags to simplify the understanding of my problem. My problem is the problem that you solve with your proposed solutions, but in your solutions there is no calculation of descending tags. For example (as you see in the last example) the calculate of the count for tags not directly descendent: A/C, A/D, A/E A/B/D, A/B/E,A/C/D etc.

Comment: I don't see any mentioning of stuff like `A/C` or `A/B/E` in the section following "the results should show" in your question. Like many people, it seems you don't have your requirements clear or you adapt them substantially once you have gotten some help. Sorry, I think I have invested enough into helping on this question.

Comment: I don't know why you don't want help me. I have given you all the explanations requested. I only asked you for a change to your proposed code. It should be quick and easy for you. But you don't want, without a reason.

Comment: As I said, you don't have precise descriptions of your requirements and once it seems some requirements have been established and solved by the answer you change them substantially. As for "quick and easy", well, do it on your own if you think you can judge the effort others have to make.

Comment: My "quick and easy" is not a judgment. I think that this is simple for you who know xpath very well. I'm sorry if you think I judge your work but respect it. If you decide to help me, I will thank you.